# Cannot find the place where username and password are stored while going through Python Django tutorials

Tags: django, userid

I'm going through Django tutorials and I'm wandering what file  the username and password information to 'mysite' get stored on. I did a search and couldn't find  them.

Comment: Which username/password? The Django tutorials typically use a SQLite database and do not need any credentials. Typically it would be in settings.py per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you create a new site in using the `startproject` command, the DATABASES setting uses an SQLite backend, which is a simple database stored in a file.  This file will be called `db.sqlite3` and appear in the same directory as your `manage.py` file.  All data is stored using this database.

SQLite is ok for local development, but you'll want to use MySQL or Postrgres when running a site in production.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This file is not a text file, that's why search did not find. The http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ page doesn't have Reset button, So if you have forgot password, you must to reinstalled project?

Comment: You can reset the password in two ways:  assuming you remember the password or are logged already, on the admin site at `/admin/` you can edit the Users, and update the password there; or using Django's shell (run `./manage.py shell` you can get the User using the ORM, and update the password using `set_password()` on the model itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm pretty new to Web programming, except using HTML did not do much for Web, though I did used Python for other applications.